# isErrorEnabled not working Kotlin Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, boolean

saasHI,

I am doing a tutorial of Authenticaton Login and Register, isErrorEnabled
and it is not working for me could you please help?

the tutorial 3rd video minute 13:00

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QkZi4Xi9Gy8&list=PLxPn1IRBtvq_Dq57j2HGIUCDI9xZlFLW1&index=4

code:

RegisterActivity kotlin class

```
private fun validateName(): Boolean{
        var errorMessage: String? = null
        val value: String = mBinding.nameBoxRegister.text.toString()
        if(value.isEmpty()){
            errorMessage = "Full name is required / Se requiere nombre completo"
        }

        if(errorMessage != null){
          mBinding.nameBoxRegister.apply {
             isErrorEnabled = false
              error = errorMessage

          }
        }
```

xml layout activity_register nameBoxRegister

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/nameBoxRegister"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/name_box_register"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
                android:paddingVertical="12dp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Tried to search online but find no answer.

Comment: Is that your ``mBinding.nameBoxRegister`` type is TextInputLayout? Can you share your code for belongs to id nameBoxRegister too, you can find all of this with your XML file.

Comment: done put the xml code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed the code your provided, change your XML like this:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:id="@+id/nameBoxRegisterTil"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/nameBoxRegister"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/name_box_register"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
            android:paddingVertical="12dp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And now you can use `isErrorEnabled` in your `RegisterActivity` with this code:

```
private fun validateName(): Boolean {
    var errorMessage: String? = null
    val value: String = mBinding.nameBoxRegister.text.toString()
    if(value.isEmpty()){
        errorMessage = "Full name is required / Se requiere nombre completo"
    }

    if(errorMessage != null){
      mBinding.nameBoxRegisterTil.apply {
         isErrorEnabled = false
          error = errorMessage

      }
    }
```

That's it! Your problem now to be solved.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I realised, I had to use an ID from TextInputLayout for isErrorEnabled and in     val value: String = mBinding.nameBoxRegister.text.toString()
 an ID  from TextEditLayout